# Efficient way of adding zeros to a String number?

Tags: java, android, string-concatenation

I would like to turn all values into the following number format, x.xxx. I am doing this fine by using a while loop and concatenating 0 to string values that do not have the correct length. However, I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this. To be more clear of what I am trying to do, here are some examples.

Ex1--Change a string value such as 2.5 to 2.500 
Ex2--Change a string value such as 2.51 to 2.510.

This is how I am currently doing this.

```
while (str.length() < 5) {
    str= str+ "0";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat`

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.000"); 
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(2.5));
```

Comment: Yes, that is much cleaner! Thank you!

Comment: Do not forget to accept answer, it your problem is solved. @portfoliobuilder

Comment: I will accept this answer once system allows me to. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Wow,that was an amazing one Reimeus!

Anywy,how is this ? :P

```
int totalLenght = str.length();

        if(totalLenght>5){
            str = str.substring(0,5);
        }else{
            int remLength = 5 - totalLenght;

            for(int i=0;i<remLength;i++){
                str = str +"0";
            }
        }
```